# Extract string from string where part of string changes every time

Tags: java

I am getting response like this 
    String result ="bla bla bla  value="1001624|Success"bla bla bla ";

I want to extract the number 1001624 when it is Success, how ever the number is id so it changes every time but Success is constant.

Comment: Can you explain in a better way.. with sample input and output?..

Comment: And please provide code. Though your most likely solution will be Regex. Or... if the | (pipe) character is constant you could simply split the string on it and the first result of the split array will be the ID number you're looking for.

Comment: I tried to put the complete result but its too big  also the stack did not allowed . so i replaced unnecessary with bla bla . thanks . :)

Comment: I cannot use result .contains("success") as the number is id which changes all time . I want to extract the number .

Comment: As @TheLostMind already requested, can you post what code you have tried or the sample input and outputs. (they can be condensed for readability ofcourse)

Comment: you can use [split](http://ideone.com/8ERB4u)

Comment: @AbhijitGujar - You can use `contains("Success")` and then `replaceAll("\\D+");` right?. Why can't you use these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value=\"[0-9]*\|Success\"

You can use the above RegEx to get this part **value="1001624|Success"** from the result.

After that you can use replace and split methods to get the number alone.

```
String output =" value="1001624|Success" "; //After getting from regex
output.replaceAll("value=\"","");
output.replaceAll("|Success\"","");
```

Now the output will contain **1001624** only.